# theme() function doesn't work with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, geom

i have run the following code yet what is inside the "theme" function doesn't work (it does not change the legend title nor the axis title). Could anyone help fix this problem ?

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = df$année, 
                y = df$nb_amb, 
                color = df$Type_amb,
                group = 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = df$année, 
            y = df$nb_hosp, 
            color = df$type_hosp,
            group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = df$année, 
            y = df$nb_ext, 
            color = df$type_ext,
            group = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text("trip"),
        axis.title.x = element_text("year"),
        legend.title = element_text("alpha"))
```

Comment: Use `+ labs(y = "nombre de séjour", x = "année", color = "type de séjour")` to set axis and legend titles. `theme` is used to set things like the font size, font color, ....

Comment: Did you try instead of `theme()` the `labs()` function? Hence `+ labs(y = "nombre de séjour", x = "année", color = "type de séjour")`?

Comment: A side note, that code is using old ggplot syntax. Now you can add the dataset name as first argument of ggplot, so `ggplot(PGS_evol_type) + ` and then avoid repeating it each time - so for example `geom_line(aes(x = année,` etc.

Comment: @stefan is right.  The help page for `theme` is slightly misleading:  it says "labels of axes" for what `axis.title.y` modifies, but what it is talking about are the things described in the help page for `element_text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the comments together, your code would look something like this:

```
ggplot(PGS_evol_type) +
  geom_line(aes(x = année, y = nb_amb, color = type_amb, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = année, y = nb_hosp, color = type_hosp, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = année, y = nb_ext, color = type_ext, group = 1)) + 
  labs(y = "nombre de séjour", x = "année", color = "type de séjour") +
  
# Theme is used for changing the look of objects, for example

  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = "14"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face = "italic", size = "12")
  )
```